# Need help setting up a sample space and determining certain outcomes

Tags: probability

This question is on a practice exam, but I don't understand the professor's given solution. Here I have given the question and my attempt at the answer.

> A sample of 2 people is taken and every person is classified according to the type of their job (assume that it is either white-collar or blue-collar) and their political affiliation (assume that it is either Republican, Democrat or Independent).
>
> a) How would you set up the sample space?
>
> b) How many outcomes are in the sample space?
>
> c) Using your notation from (a) list all outcomes in the event that neither of the people is Republican or Democrat

This is how I approached the question:

a) $S=\left\{\left((j_1,p_1),(j_2,p_2)\right):j_i=w,b,\ p_i=R,D,I\right\}$

b) I'm not really sure about this one, but here is what I think: as there are 2 choices for each $j_i$ and 3 choices for every $p_i$ which gives $(2^2)(3^2)=36$ total outcomes.

c) assuming that my notation is correct, I would have:
$$\{((w,I),(w,I)) \; \mathbf, \; ((w,I),(b,I)) \; \mathbf,\; ((b,I),(w,I)) \; \mathbf,\; ((b,I),(b,I))\}$$

I'm really hoping I have the correct answer, but if not any help will be greatly appreciated.
Thanks in advance!

(Also, sorry if the formatting is clunky, I tried my best.)

Comment: I think your c) has some formatting issues. if I assume there are parentheses where I think there should be parentheses, it looks correct to me. maybe you should post the professor's solution so we can explain their discrepancies?

Comment: @tyler I tried to bold the comma after every set of two parenthesis. I believe my professor mistakenly solved the question for a sample of 4 people instead of 2 people so he has 16 outcomes with 4 pairs in each outcome. I'll try to fix my notation, perhaps it will make it more clear.